# Ramified covering of a torus

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, geometric-topology

Let $M\to T$ be a double covering of a torus $T=S^1\times S^1$ ramified over $n$ disjoint circles. Then what is the Euler characteristics of $M$?

Comment: I know what it means for a map between 2-dimensional manifolds to be a ramified covering over a collection of points. But what does it mean to be a ramified covering over a collection of circles?

Comment: @LeeMosher : probably that the locus $\{ t \in T : \#f^{-1}(t) = 1\}$ is a circle. For example, the projection of the 2-sphere on the disk is a ramified cover branched over a circle.

Comment: That would make sense for a circle which is a boundary component of the image surface. However, in this question the image is a surface with empty boundary. So the question is quite unclear.

Comment: @LeeMosher ah of course you are right. I feel silly I answered without having noticed this, I'll modify my answer. Sorry for the silly comment.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** : if $\chi(A) = 0$ and $p :X \to Y$ is a $2$-fold covering with branch locus $A$ then $\chi(X) = 2 \chi(Y)$. (To prove it, just triangulate appropriately everything. )

**Remark** : As mentioned by Lee Mosher in the comments, this can only happens if $n=0$. Indeed, if $f : M \to N$ is a covering between surfaces ramified say along a circle $C \subset N$, and $U$ is a little neighborhood of some $c \in C$, $f^{-1}(U) \cong \{(x,y,z) : xy = 0$ in $\Bbb R^3\}$ and in particular $M$ is not a manifold. The only possibility for $n \neq 0$ is when $N$ has boundary and  the ramification locus is contained in the boundary $\partial N$.